# Can you dilute antibiotics with water just prior to administering?

Tags: rabbits, medicines

My vet gave me an antibiotic for my rabbit to take over the next 14 days. I know it tastes horrible especially with the nasty cherry flavoring they add to it and decided to dilute each dose 1:1 with water. He's now taking the medicine with significant lesser amount of fuss but is the dilution OK or will it somehow negate the antibiotics?

---

**UPDATE:**
The antibiotics he was prescribed is Trimethoprim sulfate. I spoke to a "tech vet" who said it was OK, but only after an odd hesitation. Still trying to get a hold of the actual doctor via phone for confirmation.

Comment: What was the antibiotic prescribed for?  It could be that the condition meant better to take a risk on an antibiotic that might be dangerous than allow an infection to definitely kill the rabbit.  The label use indicates for Eye issues, if you just have a common eye infection I think there are better options for your rabbit.

Comment: I was initially going to suggest it would be fine, but this drug is less effective in rabbits as a consequence of a short half-life and so I really do think it's wiser to get a vet's opinion on the impact of dilution as a result.

Comment: @Critters - Trimethoprim sulfate is quickly absorbed in the system and so usually has less impact on the good bacteria in the GI tract itself. It's also why the effectiveness can be less than some alternatives, but may be useful for a minor localized infection and is prescribed for more than eye infections.

Comment: @JohnCavan - I was just going by the label.  I am not a vet or a doctor but the [on label use](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?setid=507c7308-6526-40d7-b8aa-3ca7b5d8cc17#nlm34067-9) suggests eye infections.  In rabbits their gut is fragile enough that any risk to it is generally best avoided.  This was backed up by my vet friend that does specialize in rabbits.

Comment: @StrandedPirate, when you get an answer from your vet, please post it here.

Comment: @Critters - That's cool, I was surprised at the prescription as well, but I wanted to clarify the drug usage a bit.

Comment: I do see that there are other blends of Trimethoprim sulfate besides the one i found first.  That one is an eye medicine but there is also indications for use with fungal and protozoan infections as well.

Comment: @Critters - Yes, my Merck manual lists quite a few variants, both for topical and for ingestion. Not knowing the issue being treated, and not being a vet, I'm not likely to second guess the prescription but I did find it a bit odd.

Comment: @JohnCavan - Im not a vet but I know rabbits.  Most vets really do not understand that rabbits are so much different than other animals in terms of their immune system.  Before I learned more about rabbits I actually had a Vet diagnose pasturella infection because my rabbit had GI Stasis, despite not having any signs of actual pasterella.  Its the one term that all vets know about rabbits and it tends to get over diagnosed.  Despite the fact that actual confirmed cases of Pasterella are pretty rare.